# Using models on packages

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-4, package

I'm trying to use Laravel packages. I created MyVendor/MyPackage

Routes, controllers, filters are already working. This is the classmap of my package:

```
"classmap": [
        "src/migrations",
        "src/controllers",
        "src/seeds",
        "src/models"
    ],
```

This is how looks my model:

```
namespace MyVendor\MyPackage\Models;             
class MyModel extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {   
}
```

And this is the code inside my controller which is in namespace MyVendor\MyPackage.

```
$test = new models\MyModel;
```

I'm getting this error:
Class 'MyVendor\MyPackage\models\MyModel' not found

I can't figure out why. I'm new with namespaces so maybe it is something related to this.
I tried with composer update, composer dump-autoload (inside my package) and still can't find my models.

If I get the declared classes with get_declared_classes() I can't see my model there.

The problem is that my model classes are not autoloading.

Comment: Are you sure you are using matching case for namespace? Your error has models with a lowercase m whereas your namespace declares it uppercase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

1. Create `models` directory inside your package and add it to the package's classmap
2. Add a model `YourModel.php` with the following:

   ```
   <?php
   // Note no namespace

   use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

   class YourModel extends Eloquent {
       //
   }
   ```
3. Run `composer dump-autoload` from your package directory first and then root directory
4. Test your model by putting this at the top of your routes.php file:

   ```
   <?php
   $testModel = YourModel::get();
   die(var_dump($testModel));
   ?>
   ```

Comment: Minor hint: Laravel has the helper function dd (); Use this instead of die(var_dump()). http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#miscellaneous

Comment: @KoenBetsens Yes, but only if you prefer the output of `dd()`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

These works for me on Laravel 4.2

```
<?php namespace Vendor\Package;

use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Product extends Eloquent {

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, running `composer dump-autoload` solved the problem. Remember, once you change the model, run `composer dump-autoload` again.

laravel version: 10,
code:

```
namespace vendor\package\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class name extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```